# Windows 10 - Sort option acts differently between two folders

Tags: windows, windows-10, sorting, files-folders

I have a folder where, when I sort my files by date modified descending, all the subfolders are at the bottom. Then, in another folder, it is also sorted by date modified descending, yet the subfolders are on top. I prefer having the folders on top, however I have no clue how to achieve that with the other folder.

I also noticed that in the folder where subfolders are on top, when I right click it has a "Date Modified" and "Descending" checkmarked with a dot. The other folder doesn't checkmark either and has the descending/ascending options grayed out.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Does anyone know what setting is influencing this behavior? I'd like both folders to act the same.

Comment: When doing right-click on the folder and *Properties > Customize*, is there a difference between the two folders?

Comment: @harrymc yes, you're right, there was! one was optimized for pictures, while the other was for general items. optimizing both for pictures sorted the subfolders the way i wanted :D Thank you!

Comment: I added an answer summarizing our exchange. Please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on both folders and selecting *Properties > Customize*
found the difference between the two folders:

One was optimized for pictures while the other was optimized
for General items.

Optimizing both folders for Pictures sorted the subfolders the way
the poster wanted.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I was hoping this was a hack I could use on my system too. Dunno why it works for OP though...